# How to secure routes in [Angular 10] Secure Routes Using AuthGuard Based On User Role

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, roles

I have been checking this blog about [Angular 10] Secure Routes Using AuthGuard Based On User Role but there is no sample demo or complete process that I can check on, can anyone help me regarding the implementation of [Angular 10] Secure Routes Using AuthGuard Based On User Role which is same or similar with this blog ? so that I can tie and connect things out. Thanks.

I just wanted to fully implement Secure Routes Using AuthGuard Based On User Role in angular or angular 10.

I have a service on a back-end or I already have the routes that contain the user role, the endpoint contains the role which is the example json is below.

How do I integrate the role from the API to the guard service and Routes ? can anyone please enlighten me. Thanks.

Example Data:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "emailAddress": "test@gmail.com",
  "firstName": "Test",
  "lastName": "Test Man",
  "mobileNumber": "455555555",
  "associatedAccount": "Sample",
  "status": "Active",
  "lastLogIn": null,
  "invitedById": null,
  "invitedByDate": null,
  "identityId": "2",
  "userAccountDto": [
      {
          "id": 2,
          "accountId": 4,
          "accountName": "Sample Company 1",
          "displayName": "Sample Company",
          "settings": "{\"propertySearchFilter\":[{\"type\":\"Region\",\"values\":null},{\"type\":\"State\",\"values\":[]},{\"type\":\"Repm\",\"values\":null}]}",
          "userRoleDto": {
              "id": 2,
              "roleName": "Admin"
          },
          "accountDto": {
              "accountId": 4,
              "accountName": "Sample Company",
              "displayName": "Sample Company",
              "isActive": true,
              "contactFirstName": null,
              "contactLastName": null,
              "contactPhone": null,
              "contactEmailAddress": null,
              "accountRoleDto": [
                  {
                      "id": 1,
                      "accountId": 4,
                      "roleName": "Admin"
                  },
                  {
                      "id": 5,
                      "accountId": 4,
                      "roleName": "Transaction Manager"
                  },
              ]
          }
      },
```

https://www.geekstrick.com/angular-10-secure-routes-using-authguard-based-on-user-role/

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-role-guard-service?file=src/app/app-routing.module.ts) Guarding is used for securing routes. To use guard firstly u need to write your guide service such as below. In below code think that you get  role from UserRolesService
and  you see that canActivate function. This function is used to allow or not allow. Inside function you can check your role if you want to allow to that role return true if not return false

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UserRolesService} from './user-roles.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RoleGuardService {

  constructor(private getUserRoles: UserRolesService) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return route.data.roles.some( ai => this.getUserRoles.getRoles().includes(ai) );
  }

}
```

after you write your guard than in app.routing  u need to use canActivate attribute to activate this guard to this route.

```
    path: "admin",
        component: AdminOnlyComponent,
        canActivate: [RoleGuardService],
        data: { roles: ['admin']
}
```

Comment: Hi @pc_coder, I have updated my question above Sir, I was wondering  how can I apply the user roles from the API to the Angular 10 Secure Routes Using AuthGuard Based On User Role.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have example where the roles are from the API for example the format above that I have sent. Thanks.

Comment: with api cant show. But there are several logic to do it. with login you can get also roles and store in session. or after login you get username or user id and with this parameter you can also send request to api to get role list too . in UserRolesService you can do it you can get data there

Comment: After I get the roles on the UserRolesService Sir , what would be the next? can you provide example Sir with just using a fix json object with roles ?